# JBoss workbench exception when trying Local search

Tags: optaplanner, kie-workbench

I'm recently using optaplanner with business-central (workbench) and KIE servers on a docker container.

KIE server image: jboss/kie-server-showcase:latest
Business central image: business-central-workbench-showcase:latest

When i try to add a Local Search to my solver configuration file this error prompts:

```
Uncaught exception: Exception caught: Cannot find constant 'GREAT_DELUGE'; expecting a method name Caused by: Cannot find constant 'GREAT_DELUGE'; expecting a method name
```

And my workbench container logs this exception:

```
> 20:54:22,472 ERROR
> [org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.logger.GenericErrorLoggerServiceImpl]
> (default task-15) Error from user: admin Error ID: 833676003 Location:
> LibraryPerspective|$ProjectScreen,DRLEditor?path_uri=default://master@MySpace/Employee_Rostering/src/main/resources/employeerostering/employeerostering/ComplexScoreRules.drl&file_name=ComplexScoreRules.drl&has_version_support=true,org.kie.workbench.common.screens.messageconsole.MessageConsole,OptaPlannerSolverEditor?path_uri=default://master@MySpace/Employee_Rostering/src/main/resources/employeerostering/employeerostering/EmployeeRosteringSolverConfig.solver.xml&file_name=EmployeeRosteringSolverConfig.solver.xml&has_version_support=true,AddAssetsScreen,OptaPlannerSolverEditor?path_uri=default://master@MySpace/Employee_Rostering/src/main/resources/employeerostering/employeerostering/RotaSolverConfiguration.solver.xml&file_name=RotaSolverConfiguration.solver.xml&has_version_support=true
> Exception: Uncaught exception: Exception caught: Cannot find constant
> 'GREAT_DELUGE'; expecting a method name Caused by: Cannot find
> constant 'GREAT_DELUGE'; expecting a method name
```

This is almost a fresh project, i created it from samples (Employee rostering) and edited some data objects and the complexScoreRules.drl

What is 'GREAT_DELUGE' constant?
How do i fix it?

Comment: Great Deluge is a new value of the enum `LocalSearchType`. It was recently added as a new algorithm on optaplanner-core. Apparently optaplanner-wb can't handle it because they require some code for each `LocalSearchType`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a jira to track this issue: https://issues.redhat.com/browse/PLANNER-1806

Meanwhile, use the [OptaPlanner "Getting Started" chapter](https://docs.optaplanner.org/latestFinal/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#quickStart) instead.